# A property of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

**Problem**: **can we find an** $\alpha>0$ **such that**:

for all $n\geq 1$ there exists $b_{n}\in(a_{n},a_{n+1})$ with the property
$$\alpha\; f(b_{n}) (b_{n}-a_{n})\leq f(a_{n})$$

My thought: If $f$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}$ then we just take $\alpha=1$, but what about a general case where $f$ increasing on some intervals and decreasing on others?

Edited*

Add: According to the first two answers below this couldn't be true in general. But what if $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No true. Let $f(x)=\sin (\pi x)$ and $a_n=n$. Then $f(a_n) =0$ and $\alpha f(b_n) (b_n-a_n) >0$ for all $b_n \in  (a_n,a_{n+1})$ if $n$ is even.

Answer for the revised question. The result is true in this case. Take any $\alpha>0$.  $f(a_n) >0$ and $\alpha f(x) (x-a_n) \to 0$ as $x$ decreases to $a_n$. Hence there exists $b_n \in (a_n,a_{n+1})$ such that the inequality holds.

Comment: Oky. So what if $f(x)> 0$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Answer edited. @MathPro

Comment: Do you mean that the claim will be true in this case and we can choose any $\alpha>0$ as we take $b_{n}$ very close to $a_{n}$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said. @MathPro

Comment: One last question: Does the statemet still be true if we also require that  $b_{n}-a_{n}\geq \delta>0$ for all $n$? I think in this case $\alpha$ must play a significant rule in the inequality!

Comment: $a_n=n$ and $f(x)=e^{e^{x}}$ is a counter-example. @MathPro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112643/discussion-between-mathpro-and-kavi-rama-murthy).

Comment: How can we re-formulate the proof; the claim is to proof that for every $n=1,2,3,...$ the inequality holds and not as $n\to \infty$ ? @Kavi

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let $a_n=0$ for all $n$. We have that $b_n=0\implies b_n-a_n=0$. So LHS is always $0$. Take $f(x)=-1$ constant function. We have:
$$0 \leq -1$$

Contradiction.